# Faceted search impact on GAE datastore reads

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say I have 1000 entities. I'd like users to find entities through a faceted search in this way:

1. user selects filter
2. an ajax request is sent to GAE
3. server returns the count of matching entities
4. repeat until there are only a few entities

In other words every applied filter (just a checkbox) may cause up to 1000 reads (subsequent filters would cost less because fewer entities are returned). 
This means that about 10 "searches" (= applying multiple filters) a day may eat up all my 50k free reads quota.

Memcaching results isn't really an option: if I have 30 filters which one could apply, to store all combinations there would be 2^30="over a billion" memcache entries (which would all have to be updated when an entity changes by making first a billion datastore reads).

evidently I didn't get something. How would I efficiently cache or calculate results?

Comment: Do you just need the count of filtered entities or actual entities also?  In my experience the count should never be calculated on the fly in any case.  Sharded/memcached counters should be kept upto date when the data is written.

Comment: @Yasser, first I just need the count, to give an immediate feedback to the user. But, as I explained in the question, I can't store all of "the counters" the would correspond to a "filter combination" since there would be a really really really really large number of those counters, that all would need to be updated when something changes (making the whole point useless).

Comment: I added an answer which suits your situation well in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a 1000 or so entities, your best bet, given the situation you have described, is to keep all 1000 entities in memcache and run your queries in memory instead of the datastore.  In-memory query of a 1000 entities should be very fast.

You can convert your entities to protobufs before storing in memcache.  See this [link](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching).

Comment: Seems legit. Actually I'll try to query on clientside. Compressing the 1000 entity "filter associations" in 32bit masks, which shouldn't need more than 12kB for the whole package when JSON encoded. (4kB if the browser supports typed arrays)

Answer (score 2):

Don't attempt to implement this yourself - use the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/), which is designed for efficiently returning results in exactly this sort of situation.

Comment: would that allow me to get a count of results while increasing the api call quota "once per query" and not "one for each result"?

Comment: @Roman Check out the docs, which I linked, for details on how it works. It uses separate quotas to the datastore.